# Is Google Maps blocking me?

Tags: google-maps, blocking, google-maps-static-api

I'm programming web application that works with Google Maps and I need to generate PDF output so I decided to use static API. My application will be using set of 1500 small map images (100*100px). I dont want to ask Google for every image thousand times a day so I wrote a script to download all images and save it to my server where images will be used from. After downloading 300 images my server gets this error:

```
Warning: readfile(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=100x100&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://mediup.martinstrouhal.cz/arrs/210.png%7Cshadow:false%7C50.078522,14.436551&sensor=false&zoom=16) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

Does this mean that google is blocking me permanently?

Comment: I have a feeling that doing this (pdf output) might be against the ToS. Might want to read over that. Other possibilites to use would be the [openstreetmaps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) project.

Comment: Czech people would download everything if they could. Hope google will not ban us all :-)

Comment: There was sleep(2) in each cycle. I hope I will be unbanned. Tomas T: I want do download images to my local cache to prevent beeing banned! But I was banned during caching :-(

Comment: It is against ToS to download static maps and create PDF's out of them. Eventually you will be permanently blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that Google Maps has a throttle on it that will cut off anyone abusing the API. Since you are just storing the images, put a random wait in between each request and let it run for a long time until you get all the images you need.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Does that mean that my ban is not permanent?

Comment: I would be _very_ surprised if your ban was not lifted soon. I would expect 24 hours or less, but if you are concerned, read through the Terms of Service or Terms of Use for the static API and send an email to the contact address in there.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the API key.

Without including your API key The Streetview Images API is throttled by IP to 1000 images per 24 hours and 5 images per minute, both of which you are likely to hit if you do not use the key. With the key you can pull 25000 images / day

Format should be:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&sensor=false&key=API_KEY

Docs for streetview include how to get an API key. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?csw=1

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you are using the Static Maps API or if you are doing direct tile access.

Direct tile access is prohibited by Google, so they will block you if the server suspects you're pulling down tiles for caching. They don't state the limits on this for security reasons.

Static Maps has a limit of 2500 per day per IP address, but it is throttled as to how many you can pull down per second.

In any case, using Static Maps or direct tile access to save imagery for later use is against Google's ToS.

Comment: Thank you for your information. If they will unblock me I will use maps without caching

Comment: In my experience the blocks usually last 24hrs before they are lifted.

Answer (score 1):

According to many sources Googled - the ban lasts for 24 hours but found no really official answer on that.

Perhaps you could inform us how long your ban was.

Comment: I got several bans lasting between 8 and 12 hours